# Calculate the difference between multiple values belonging to a group

Tags: r

I am a bit stuck on a specific problem in R, for which I only have a a long-winded and unelegant solution. Maybe somebody knows a better way of doing this.
Lets say we have a data frame like this:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C")
z <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 4, 4,4)
y <- c(43, 32, 45, 32, 22, 52, 23, 13, 12, 4, 12, 5)
df <- data.frame(x,z,y)
```

with the data looking like this: [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrx6N.png)

I am trying to calculate the difference between the y values within the x groupings, depending on z. E.g. the difference between A of group 1 and A of group 2 (43-22=21) and A of group 2 and A of group 3 (22-12=10) and so on.
I can do this very ugly like this:

```
ordered.df<-df[order(df$z, df$x),]
bl<-ordered.df[ordered.df$z==1,]
bl2<-ordered.df[ordered.df$z==2,]
bl3<-ordered.df[ordered.df$z==3,]
bl4<-ordered.df[ordered.df$z==4,]

first <- bl$y - bl2$y
second <- bl2$y - bl3$y
third <- bl3$y - bl4$y
ycolumn <- c(first,second,third)
xcolumn <- rep(c("A","B","C"),3)
zcolumn <- rep(1:3,each=3)
final.df <- data.frame(xcolumn,zcolumn,ycolumn)
```

and was wondering if there is any more elegenat and scalable solutions.

Ultimately, I want to count the occurances of positive differences:

```
final.df$lower <- 0
final.df$lower[final.df$ycolumn>0] <- 1
aggregate(lower ~ zcolumn, final.df, sum)
```

Any suggestions are welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `mutate` for each group:

```
library(dplyr)
final.df <- df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(y = y - lead(y, 1)) %>%
  arrange(z, x) %>%
  filter(!is.na(y))
final.df

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
  x         z     y
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1    21
2 B         1     0
3 C         1    -7
4 A         2    10
5 B         2    19
6 C         2    29
7 A         3     0
8 B         3     9
9 C         3    18
```

And use `summarise` for the aggregate:

```
final.df %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  summarise(lower = sum(y > 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      z lower
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     3
3     3     2
```

Comment: Fyi `sum(y > 0)` should be the same as the ifelse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table one-liner

```
setDT(df)[, list(z = z, y_diff = y - shift(y, 1, type = "lead")), by = .(x = x)][ y_diff > 0, list(lower = .N), by = "z"]

#   z lower
#1: 1     1
#2: 2     3
#3: 3     2
```

what it does:
`setDT(df)`
make a data.table out of `df`

`[, list(z = z, y_diff = y - shift(y, 1, type = "lead")), by = .(x = x)]`
group by x, subtract the next y from the current y and create column `y_diff` with the outcome

`[ y_diff > 0, list(lower = .N), by = "z"]`
for all rows where `y_diff`  is greater than 0, give the number of rows (=`.N`), grouped by `z`

Comment: Filtering y_diff > 0 will drop z values with 0 observations. Could instead sum(y_diff > 0).Fwiw, another variation: `setDT(df)[, .(z = head(z, -1), -diff(y)), by=x][, .(n = sum(V2 > 0)), by=z]`

Answer (score 1):

If you actual data only has a small number of groups (z), but large number of categories (x), you can convert the data to wide format and start from there. Here is a solution for the simple example.

```
> library(data.table)
> library(reshape2)
> 
> df_reshape = dcast(x~z, data=df, value.var="y")
> setDT(df_reshape)
> setnames(df_reshape,c(as.character(seq(1,4,1))),c(paste("x",as.character(seq(1,4,1)), sep="")))
> head(df_reshape)
   x x1 x2 x3 x4
1: A 43 22 12 12
2: B 32 32 13  4
3: C 45 52 23  5
> df_reshape[,.(diff1=x1-x2,diff2=x2-x3,diff3=x3-x4),by=x][,.(group1 = sum(diff1>0),group2 =sum(diff2>0),group3 = sum(diff3>0))]
   group1 group2 group3
1:      1      3      2
```